# Get the last value on future

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

Im doing a flutter app for currency exchange, on the call of the function to print the value, only get the last value for all

basically this only get the last value of `getvalue` and put for all of the values.

```
class BodyWidgetState extends State<BodyWidget> {
  @override

        Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold (
    appBar: AppBar(title: Text(moed)),
    body: ListView(
      children: <Widget> [
        ListTile (
          leading: CircleAvatar(
            backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/mxn.png'),
          ),
          title: Text('MXN'),
        ),
        getValue(moed,'MXN'),
        ListTile(

          leading: CircleAvatar(
            backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/eur.png'),
          ),
          title: Text('EUR'),
        ),
        getValue(moed,'EUR'),
```

---

```
         Widget getValue (String b, String c){
      return (
     FutureBuilder<Quote> (
      future : getQuote(b,c),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return Center(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(height: 10),
              Text(snapshot.data.coin.toString()),
                ],
              ));
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text("${snapshot.error}");
        }
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      }));}
```

Comment: hi, could you share what is inside getQuote() function? and inside getValue()?

Comment: well, if you could share the whole code through github or so it would be awesome

Comment: https://github.com/hugomvsv/currency ty for interest